# Calculating Stream Length-gradient Index (Hack Index) with the field calculator

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I'm trying to calculate the Stream Length-Gradient Index of a stream (example data below). Just started to get into python, but am struggling with a solution to this problem. I have 42 streams to run this code on and doing it by with excel is tedious. The stream is broken up into segments and I'd like to get a SL index for each stream.

The equation: SL = (10/Length of segment)*(sum(length of segments) * (length of segment/2))

In each stream attribute table I have:

Length

69.98             <-- top of stream

90.228

94.206

85.429

94.039

99.095

92.983

76.736

56.657 <----head of stream

Now the biggest hickup I have is that all the data is backwards I need to run the calculation from the head of the stream (bottom of the attribute table) to the top of the stream.

Thanks!

Comment: so each row in your stream attribute table corresponds to a segment?

Comment: Yeah, each row is a segment length

Comment: does this table indicate the next downstream segment, too? Or is the routing topology stored elsewhere? If you have more to add, might just edit the original post.

Comment: It does not, other than the last value is the furthest point down slope and the first is the hightest point upstream

Comment: Your formula does not appear to compute a stream length index: this calculation depends on elevation differences as well as lengths, at least according to one of Hack's original papers (http://www.ees.lehigh.edu/ftp/retreat/outgoing/roma_tre_short_course/Hack_USGS_1973.pdf).  Is it possible that your stream has been broken into segments of equal elevation drop?  Even then the last factor in the formula is mysterious; it does not seem to have any equivalent in the paper.

Comment: @whuber The delta H for the calculation is 10m, contours that were used to split the full length of the stream. Delta L is the length of the segment (segment of stream between each contour interval)

Comment: Yes, that is what I was guessing : but what is `(length of segment/2))` doing in the formula?

Comment: @whuber It was my shortcut to find L, length of the midpoint of the segment to the basin divide.

Comment: It seems you are using the terms `length of segment` in your formula for two different things, then.

Comment: @whuber Thats all you need to compute the SL Index for the selected segment (sum of lengths - (half the segments distance)) = mid point of the segment to the basin divide: L, unless I haven't had enough coffee today and am looking at this backwards

Comment: Well, I'll let this drop then.  I'll just conclude by saying I cannot connect your formula as stated to the one in Hack's paper, which I believe will return a substantially different value.  If you're sure it's right, by all means go ahead and implement it.  But you ought to consider checking it, perhaps by reproducing a published calculation.

Comment: I agree with @whuber in that you should revisit the equation.  I did some initial calculations using your formula and it did not pass the logic test!

Answer (score 1):

looking at the formula again, I'm realizing that there is no need for accumulation of lengths up/downstream. Makes things much simpler.

You can use [`Statistics`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0008/00080000001z000000.htm&ei=EBX0UuzLIM_ooAS66oDABA&usg=AFQjCNEBpWMAocRYYKJF3BBWRx7A87fP7w&bvm=bv.60983673,d.cGU) to sum the length for the table/the stream in question.  You can then use something like the following to capture that value

```
csr = arcpy.SearchCursor('TableViewOfStatsOutput)
row = csr.next()
sumLength= row.getValue("SUM_Length")
```

Then you should be able to write your formula into an `CalculateField` statement and get your answer.